# Using Spire.PDF to merge pdf files Errors

Tags: vb.net, pdf

I am using the free licenced version of Spire PDF. My program has in the region of 166,ooo pdf files which represent individual pages. I need to merge between 1 and 20 of these with the same names into one pdf.

I have a routine the builds a string of filenames to be added to an array which is passed to the following sub as PDFFiles. The OutputFile is the string with the name of the output file with it's path.

```
      Private Sub MergePDFs(ByVal PDFFiles As String, ByVal OutPutFile As String)
    Dim files As [String]() = New [String]() {"E:\Ballads of the 20th Century\1st bari #1.pdf", "E:\Ballads of the 20th Century\1st bari #2.pdf"}
    Dim i As Integer
    'open pdf documents            
    Dim docs As PdfDocument() = New PdfDocument(files.Length - 1) {}
    For i = 0 To files.Length - 1
        docs(i) = New PdfDocument(files(i))
    Next

    'append document
    docs(0).AppendPage(docs(1))

    'import PDF pages
    i = 0
    While i < docs(2).Pages.Count
        docs(0).InsertPage(docs(2), i)
        i = i + 2
    End While
End Sub
```

I have the Solution  Explorer I have the Spire.Pdf.dll as a file. In References I have Spire.Pdf and Spire.Licence.

At runtime I get An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Spire.Pdf.dll
Additional information: File doesn't exist.

The PDFFiles is not used in this example for clarity. The two files listed are taken directly from the program output for testing purposes.

There has to be a simple explanation for this error, but I haven't found one yet.

Please can you help solve it.
Thanks
Graham

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this myself.

The actual problem was the way Spire.pdf parses a string into a pdf document.
There must be no spaces in the filename, then it works fine.

Graham